# Multiple Dialog Boxes

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am having an issue with Dialogs in jquery, I have a query that plops up to 4 items of data into a div, in a loop. I want to have each row available for more information via a dialog box.

**IN HEAD TAG:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>     


<script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 500
      }
    });

    $( ".opener" ).click(function() {
      $( ".dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  });
  </script>
```

**PHP:**

```
foreach($veh as $v){
        echo '<div class="block">';

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
            $result = $dbh->query($sql); 
            $row = $result->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    foreach($row as $r){            

        echo '<div class="effect6">'.strtoupper($r['col_name']).'</div>';
        echo '<div id="dialog" title="'.$r['eas_no'].'">Text</div>';
        echo '<button id="opener">Open</button>';
                            }

                echo '</div>';

                }
```

**EDIT**
Every Single Dialog box now opens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your code to this:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 500
      }
    });

    $( ".opener" ).bind("click", function() {
        var selectorClass = ".dialogDiv" + $(this).attr("id");
        $(selectorClass).dialog( "open" );
    });
  });
</script>
```

and

```
$tmp = 0; 
foreach($row as $r) {            

    echo '<div class="effect6">'.strtoupper($r['col_name']).'</div>';
    echo '<div class="dialogDiv'.$tmp.' dialog" title="'.$r['eas_no'].'">Text</div>';
    echo '<button class="opener" id="'.$tmp.'">Open</button>';
    $tmp++;    
   }
```

Comment: why would changing an ID into a CLASS make a difference?

Comment: Because you can have only one ID on page, ID is unique. Class is not unique, and you can use it to reference your dialog. As @Uberfuzzy sad

Comment: Ok im half way now, thanks. They are opening now, just EVERY SINGLE ONE opens about 109.

Comment: Still zero mate, I am in unknown territory now so I cant even help myself. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27552/discussion-between-oliverb-and-freshbm)

Answer (score 1):

You are making multiple things with same id (`dialog` and `opener`). id are supposed to be unique on page

Comment: Ok mr obvious. Haha, ok now I need to get some brain cells working. Any tips on getting fresh ids in the jquery (newbie) i can sort it for the php side